# Automatic correction of many topological errors in shapefile?

Tags: qgis, vector, qgis-processing, topology

I have a database with topological error. In particular I have an overlay of polygons. I would like to correct these errors.

I thought to use an automatic procedure since I have a lot of errors. I thought to use the v.clean command in grass (I use QGIS).

The command works well but it creates many additional geometries.

Is there a method to avoid this problem?
[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Comment: Are overlays errors or should there be some? Post some printscreens of errors and what settings you used on v.clean. Also check this post, it might help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/324211/16109

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer. I update the question with 2 image of my situation. I'm working with a large database of polygon. I tried to run v.clean algorithm from qgis platform with the standard option. Also, I tried to run command from Grass, in this case I used the following command: rmdupl,rmdangle,snap,rmdac,prune,rmsa. The command seems to function, I obtained at the end this warning message: number of incorrect borders: 2922 and number of centroids outside the area:2048.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Geometry Checker plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_geometry_checker.html). 
Just leave the the value of "Check for overlaps smaller than ..." equal 0.0 and run. In the next window, click "Fix selected errors using default resolution". Take a look [here](https://www.northrivergeographic.com/archives/qgis-2-12-check-geometries-plugin), it might help.

Geometry Checker is a core plugin, so it is already installed. You just need to go to activate it in the Plugin Manager. Go to the installed tab and click on Geometry Checker. Take a look [here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/qgis_plugins/fetching_plugins.html).

Comment: OP stated that v.clean was not a solution. Without a much more explicit answer, this Answer may be deleted as *low-quality*.

Comment: @Vince, you were right. I usually fix this problem using v.clean under my own PyQGIS algorithm, that's why I said to use it. Considering that the solution was vague, I suggest to use the Geometry Checker plugin.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers! I use the qgis version 3.6 and I can't find this plugin. Do you know a plugin for this version? or should I install the previous version and then 2.18?

Comment: @matte85, Geometry Checker is a core plugin, so it is already installed. You just need to go to activate it in the Plugin Manager. Go to the installed tab and click on Geometry Checker. Take a look here: https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/qgis_plugins/fetching_plugins.html